# How to umount non-sudo sshfs created directory

Tags: command-line, sudo, umount

I used sshfs without sudo to create a directory like

```
sshfs user@172.19.76.226:/media/user/harddrive /temp/user/harddrive
```

but when I want to umount the `/temp/user/harddrive` directory with

```
umount /temp/user/harddrive
```

it prompts:

```
umount: /temp/user/harddrive: Permission denied
```

so how to umount this directory?

Comment: Is the drive still mounted there? Please [edit] and provide the output of `mount`.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using? `lsb_release -r` shows it if you don’t know.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`sshfs` uses FUSE (File system in USErspace) instead of the regular `mount` with elevated permissions.

That also means you can not use `umount` (the counterpart of `mount`) to unmount the file system though, but you have `fusermount -u`, the FUSE unmount command:

```
fusermount -u /temp/user/harddrive
```

For more info, see e.g. `man sshfs` and `man fusermount`.

Comment: Note that [the 17.10 and 18.04 manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/sshfs.1.html) explicitly say “unmounting: `umount mountpoint`” while until 16.04 it’s `fusermount -u mountpoint` instead – guess it’s different for different releases!

Comment: This fails on Ubuntu 20.04 with the message: "fuse: bad mount point `/temp/user/harddrive': Input/output error". I have never seen a sshfs get properly unmounted without using `sudo`.

Answer (score 7):

This answer refers to Ubuntu 20.04, but in general you need two steps to properly unmount a `sshfs` volume: i) kill the `sshfs` process and ii) use `sudo` to unmount. Without using `sudo`, the system reports messages like "Device or resource busy" or "Transport endpoint is not connected", even if permissions are correct.

The instructions look like:

```
killall sshfs
sudo umount -l /temp/user/harddrive
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I've bumped into this post and did not want to `kill` the process, just wanted to let you know that, as of Ubuntu 22.04, a simple `umount` works fine:

```
umount /mount/point/sshfs/folder
```

I did not get any warning or error message and the process was indeed terminated after checking with `ps aux | grep ssh`